# Riemann sum of $f(x)= x+1 $ on $[-1,4]$

Tags: calculus

I tried to find the Riemann sum of $f(x)= x+1 $ on $[-1,4]$ but I do not how to take the partition and then evaluate $R(f,P_n)= \sum_{k=0}^{k=n-1} (x_{k+1}-x_k)f(\epsilon_k)$ dividing the interval in $n$ equal parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to calculate the Riemann sum of $f(x)=x+1$ on $[-1,4]$ and the base can be calculated as follows $\Delta x = [4-(-1)]/n=5/n$. Now, the $k$ term of the height is $f_k(-1 + k\Delta x)$  so our Riemann sum will be:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(-1 + k\Delta x) \Delta x$$

Note that $f_k(-1 + k\Delta x)=(-1 + k\Delta x)+1=k\Delta x=k(5/n)$. So back to the Riemann sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{5k}{n} \frac{5}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{25k}{n^2}=\frac{25(n+1)}{2n}$$
and now taking the limit for $\Delta x \to 0$ or as $n\to \infty$

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{25(n+1)}{2n} = \frac{25}{2}$$
in fact:

$$\int_{-1}^{4} {x+1}\,dx = \frac{25}{2}$$

Comment: EDIT: added the explanation of the height.

Comment: Please note that my solution is an upper sum (or right sum). If you want a left approximation, let the height be $f_k(-1+(k-1)\Delta x)=(k-1)\Delta x$.